# Trouble specifying path to open Excel woorbook in vb.net app

Tags: vb.net, excel, search, path, vba

I have a WFP app that works well.  I open an Access DB and want to do the same with an Excel workbook.  Opening the DB is not an issue as I am able to remove the drive letter from the path.  I am having a bit of an issue with the search path for the workbook.  My path operates as expected  when the drive letter is specified [here is the line of code that works properly -- xlWorkBook_AR = xlApp_AR.Workbooks.Open("S:\11_2017_Spring\MPRecords-2\Accounting\FinancialSystem.xlsm")]).  When I remove the drive specification from the path it does not operate as expected.  I receive an error stating the file is not found.  What do I need to do to make this dynamic?
Thanks in advance.
Ed

Comment: I believe that you have to specify where the excel file lives. Why not put the file on a server?

Comment: @codeMonger123 --I would prefer to install on a server. This is a school project and needs to run from different locations on the schools hardware (i.e., desktop in class or VMware). Not a set path. Stinks, but am receiving little to no help from school (to be honest I think this is part of the class-teach them how to figure things out). The Access DB path I discovered works fine without the drive letter but I am unable to figure out the Excel path structure to make it "portable", so to speak. Thanks Ed

Comment: How is the excel being a populated, IE how is giving you the excel?

Comment: What about linking the excel file as an external data source? So you connect to the Access DB, Access retrieves the data from the spreadsheet and you can treat it as a table.

Comment: @codeMonger123--Excel file is supplied by a teammate as a standalone multi-worksheet workbook.  I call the workbook and pass control to Excel.  I retain ability to edit other parts of the app while Excel stays open.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Adam Vincent-The plan is to enter/manipulate data in the workbook and save out as separate entity. Thanks for the idea.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if it works for your scenario):

1. Place the excel file in the same folder as your app (.exe)  (I assume this works for your needs).
2. Use this code to dynamically get the path of your app, and then add on the name of the file, something like the below:

   Application.StartupPath & "\FinancialSystem.xlsm"

Supply this to excel's .Open method and I believe it will work.

You will need to import System.Windows.Forms. Read about Application.StartupPath property here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx

Comment: attempted this idea.  I must be missing something as the example on the msdn site does not work.  Error states "'Application' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Windows.Forms, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames'."

Comment: In your code - when you are calling the method on the Application object - since it is ambiguous - you need to fully define its namespace, so instead of saying "Application.StartupPath & "\FinancialSystem.xlsm"  try this instead:  "System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\FinancialSystem.xlsm"

Comment: Also - I see its a WPF app.  If you google how to get application path in wpf - there will be ways to do this without using the System.Windows.Forms namespace (which is for Winforms - UI technology previous to WPF).  Maybe this will work for you:  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  to return the path of the app exe.

Comment: @ M. Ferry  -- Thanks for the ideas.